# Citrus strip aerosol can

Tags: painting

I noticed they have Citrus strip in an aerosol can, I was wondering how easy it is to apply compared to the stuff in the bottle?

Comment: This question is very broad and is asking for an opinion about a commercial product which is off topic here. You might get a better answer by contacting the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to use just because it's a spray. It's no different that using spray paint. Since it's an aerosol spray, it disperses a lot of vapors that you would not have using the gel or liquid products. The can warns to use in well ventilated areas which the other products don't warn against. The biggest drawback is it's twice the price as the liquid and considering that the liquid goes on really fast with a brush and is cleaned up with water. The ease in using it doesn't warrant paying twice as much and breathing the fumes.

Comment: Plus the waste of over spray.

Comment: Alright, thanks for this detailed response

Answer (score 1):

Brush is **far** more accurate as you can mask and do tight areas without the spray force lifting tape etc.

So, if you are doing large flat areas then spray but fiddly bits then brush.